# Migration to Spring boot 3.1.0 and hibernate 6.2.x: Causes an ArrayOutOfBounds when executing Query

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, hibernate, jpql

While migrating to spring boot 3.1.0 with hibernate 6.2.4.Final, we found out that some of our integration tests fail due to an IndexOutOfBounds error.
`org.hibernate.sql.results.internal.TupleMetadata.getList(TupleMetadata.java:52)`

> After analysis it's the root cause was due to the `hibernate-core/src/main/java/org/hibernate/sql/results/internal/TupleMetadata.java`

```
final TupleElement<?>[] array = new TupleElement[index.size()];
            for ( Map.Entry<TupleElement<?>, Integer> entry : index.entrySet() ) { 
                array[entry.getValue()] = entry.getKey(); // <-- Array out of bounds
            }
            this.list = list = Collections.unmodifiableList( Arrays.asList( array ) );
```

A fix for the TupleMetadata class is available on this pull request [hibernate PR](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/pull/6685/files#diff-8138079eb60e4f269c1ffe8ead003a5ad05f1850b35ba9084079c2c249a87e08)

Original Jira bug description and how to reproduce can be found [here](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/jira/software/c/projects/HHH/issues/HHH-16742)

Based on all this we have three options:

1. Wait for the 6.3.0 version, that's unrealistic.
2. Rollback to 5.6.x version of hibernate
3. Find a workaround

That brings us to the main topic, does anyone know a way to override the behaviour of TupleMetadata (I know it's not wise to do so, but I'm looking for the best bad-solution available)

Comment: (hi & welcome!) The "best" (hibernate indep.) solution to this (like to any) problem: make it "no issue": ...how difficult is/it possible to remove "duplicate aliases"??;)

Comment: The effort to "replace" `...hibernate...internal...` seems huge (and 6.3.0 more realistic...to me, but willing to learn:)

Comment: (Hi & thank you)
Well there's a first time to everything, I'll update the answer with the solution. Hopefully they'll be a valid workaround/fix until 6.3.0 is released. 
As for removing "duplicate aliases" I honestly don't understand exactly how it'll fix our problem. I'll do more research and update this answer with the final verdict.

Comment: with "duplicate aliases" i mean(/most criticise) these: `select name as Reference, name as Name from ...` (since it seems nor useful nor "standard" *and* causes "issue")

Comment: I'm surprised it was this simple to fix removing the "NULLS LAST" was enough of a fix:
For example:
"ORDER BY someAttribute DESC NULLS LAST, name" => "ORDER BY someAttribute DESC, name"
It did the trick at least for one of the queries

Comment: Issue related to: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76363746/nulls-first-last-override-no-longer-works-in-jpa-repositories-in-spring-boot-3-h